# BitDefender could not delete suspicious files

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, bitdefender

I Logged-in with an Administrator user. When I scan my Transcend flash memory with my BitDefender Anti-virus, It find 36 virus :

[image]

As you see above, I click on `Delete Files` and then I click on `Continue` :

After a moment, the above windows appear again! but the options are gone!

[image]

I Inevitably click on continue! It emphasize that it can't do anything! why?
[image]

Note : Files are not password protected!

Comment: Disconnect the flash drive, reconnect, Open a command prompt, and check if these files are actually there.

Comment: @AshishKulkarni Yes! It is there!

Comment: Why can't you delete the files manually?  What are the permissions on these files?  I suggest using a security product that allows you to scan the files outside of Windows.  You should also verify these files are actually malicious and not simply a false postive.

Comment: If you look carefully, you'll see all those files are detected as *generic* threats, which make me think they triggered the BitDefender heuristic engine. Now, whether they're actually malicious it's hard to tell without analyzing them. At the very least you could try uploading some of them to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/), for example. As long as they're not important files (check that before proceeding, as suggested by Ramhound) and you're unable to delete them no matter what, try using the [BitDefender Rescue CD](http://bit.ly/1dZA4ON) or some Linux live distribution.